# Java 8 lists containing generics of mixed (but inheritance-related) types

Tags: java, generics, java-8

Java 8 here, seeing inexplicable compiler errors regarding generics.

I have `RunnableRule`:

```
public interface RunnableRule<INPUT,OUTPUT> {
    OUTPUT execute(INPUT input, OUTPUT previousOutput);
}
```

And then `AbstractRuleRunner`:

```
public abstract class AbstractBaseRuleRunner<INPUT,OUTPUT> {

    private List<RunnableRule<INPUT,OUTPUT>> rules;

    public AbstractBaseRuleRunner(List<RunnableRule<INPUT, OUTPUT>> rules) {
        this.rules = rules;
    }

    protected abstract OUTPUT initOutput();

    public OUTPUT runRules(INPUT input) {

        OUTPUT output = null;
        for (RunnableRule<INPUT,OUTPUT> rule : rules) {

            if (output == null) {
                output = initOutput();
            }

            output = rule.execute(input, output);

        }

        return output;

    }


}
```

Then some beans:

```
public interface HasPlaintextPassword {
    String getPlaintextPassword();
}

@Data
public class SignUpRequest implements HasPlaintextPassword {

    @NotNull
    private String email;

    @NotNull
    private String password;

    @NotNull
    private String appRefId;

    private boolean ackTerms;

    @Override
    public String getPlaintextPassword() {
        return getPassword();
    }

}
```

Finally a concrete implementation of my rules runner:

```
public class SignUpValidationRulesRunner extends AbstractBaseRuleRunner<HasPlaintextPassword, ValidationReport> {

    public SignUpValidationRulesRunner(List<RunnableRule<HasPlaintextPassword, ValidationReport>> runnableRules) {
        super(runnableRules);
    }

    @Override
    protected ValidationReport initOutput() {
        return new ValidationReport();
    }

}
```

A concrete runnable rule:

```
public class AcksTermsSignUpRule implements RunnableRule<SignUpRequest, ValidationReport>, RuleConstants {

    @Override
    public ValidationReport execute(SignUpRequest signUpRequest, ValidationReport previousOutput) {

        if (!signUpRequest.isAckTerms()) {
            previousOutput.getErrors().add(MUST_ACK_TERMS_ERROR);
        }

        return previousOutput;

    }

}
```

Some rules will accept `SignupRequest` as input because they need to use certain properties that are on a `SignUpRequest`, and some rules just need to accept a `HasPlaintextPassword` as input because they are just inspecting the password property.

And finally some glue to stick it all together:

```
List<RunnableRule<HasPlaintextPassword, ValidationReport>> signUpValidationRules = new ArrayList<>();
AcksTermsSignUpRule acksTermsSignUpRule = new AcksTermsSignUpRule();

signUpValidationRules.add(acksTermsSignUpRule);
```

Here I get a compiler error on `signUpValidationRules.add(acksTermsSignUpRule)` stating that the required type is `RunnableRule` but only a `AcksTermsSignUpRule` is provided.

What can I do to make it so that my list of rules accepts either `HasPlaintextPassword` or `SignUpRequest` as the input generic parameter? Because I need to combine rules of either input type inside the same list.

Comment: Try searching for wildcards and `? extends A` or `? super A` syntax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `<? super RunnableRule<?,?>>` in this case:

```java
 List<? super RunnableRule<?,?>> list = new ArrayList<>();
 list.add(new AcksTermsSignUpRule());
 list.add(new RunnableRule<String, Double>() {});
```

You could read docs right [there](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/wildcards.html)

> Collection<?> (pronounced "collection of unknown"), that is, a
> collection whose element type matches anything
>
> A lower bounded wildcard restricts the unknown type to be a specific
> type or a super type of that type. A lower bounded wildcard is
> expressed using the wildcard character ('?'), following by the super
> keyword, followed by its lower bound: <? super A>.